# Stative Verbs in Present Perfect Tense to Refer Recent Past

Tags: verbs, american-english, present-perfect, british-english, stative-verbs

> "I have just wanted to ask a question."

I was told above sentence is not valid and natural to refer recent past and "just" cannot mean here "very recently".( Recent past usage of present perfect tense) Because "wanted to ask" denotes a state not an action therefore it doesn't mean an observable completed event where there is a start and finish.

Therefore the sentence " I have just wanted to ask a question" only means a situation where "wanted to ask" has been continuing for some time to the present and "just" means "simply" or "only".

Can you explain if this is true? 
Only rule with regard to stative verbs in English is they shouldn't be used with progressive tenses. I haven't come accross any information that explain my example in any English teaching material even in present perfect tense subject.

Comment: While I appreciate the quick accept, [you may want to consider waiting a while first](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer).

Comment: Ok sorry I wasn't aware of this :)  By the way what do you think about below post that excludes "just " from present perfect? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoever told you that was oversimplifying a bit. (And [the idea that statives can't be used with progressive tenses is *also* oversimplified](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56484/is-it-allowed-to-use-stative-verbs-in-their-progressive-form), as I stated in an answer there.)

It's true that in this sort of case, "just" is almost certainly used to mean "only" instead of "recently". But stative verbs in English simply aren't that hard-and-fast a category, so there's a bit of wiggle room that could allow someone to use "just" in an unusual way for wordplay. This is especially true because the idiomatic way to mean "only" is

> "I just wanted to ask a question."

I think this is because "just", in the sense of "very recently", makes less sense to use with something in the more distant past, which tends to make it more obvious that "only" is the correct meaning.

But using present perfect instead of past tense implies that there's some present relevance: that maybe you still do want to ask the question. And that brings back up the possibility of meaning "very recently".

There is an unambiguous way to refer to the recent past using "just", though:

> "I just now wanted to ask a question."

(At a time in the very immediate past, I had a particular desire, and probably still do.)

> "I just started wanting to ask a question."

(Beginning in the very immediate past and continuing, I have had a particular desire.)

You should avoid using an unusual and ambiguous construction like "I have just wanted…" unless you have a very good reason. Either of the two possible meanings can be phrased more clearly.

Comment: Many thanks Nathan for your valuable inputs, appreciated! I think the teachers I asked stuck to the word "action" in recent past definition of the present perfect tense.  "Just want to ask/do" something in recent past didn't mean any context to them. So what I understand,  no matter it is a stative verb "want to do" something can start and finish. (Maybe that's why I haven't seen any warning unlike progressive usage of stative verbs in grammar sources as mentioned in my post) There might be always exceptional usages but important thing is to avoid ambiguity as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

At the outset: **just** can mean "only" or it can have a temporal meaning, "a moment ago" or "not long ago", or, with some verbs, "recently". I don't believe that **want** is one of those verbs, except in very rare situations. To say "I have just wanted..." makes semantic sense only if you're recounting your mental state moment-by-moment.

We can use the present perfect with **want** to indicate that the want has existed recently and has continued to exist up to the present moment:

> I have wanted our paths to cross for some time now.

In its sense of "a moment ago", **just** is incompatible with the present perfect because "just" situates the action in the past, albeit the recent past, not along a continuum that extends from the past up to the present moment. A time phrase in a present perfect construction cannot exclude the present.

> I just saw him a moment ago.
>
> I have just seen him a moment ago.  <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

P.S. If the semantics of the sentence allow for the meaning **recently**, then **just** can be used with the present perfect, provided there are no other time phrases that relegate the action to the past:

> I have just come from there.
>
> I have just come from there an hour ago. <sup>ungrammatical</sup>
>
> I have just seen her.
>
> I have just seen her a second ago. <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your reply however I think you are more explaining a different approach mostly accepted by American usage. I've never thought "just" is incompatible with present perfect. I don't think there is consensus regarding this matter. According to this logic present perfect shouldn't be used with any recent past action/situation. Here is a link that might give more input: https://jakubmarian.com/i-just-did-it-vs-i-have-just-done-it-present-perfect-or-past-simple/

Comment: @Bart: No, according to this logic, a time phrase that relegates the action to the past should not be used with the present perfect. With respect to the false claim that this rule would prevent the use of the present perfect with recent events, you have not paid attention to what I wrote about "a continuum that extends from the past up to the present moment".  This has nothing to do with "American usage".

Comment: Thanks.Let's clarify this way. http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/present-perfect/ Do you agree "actions completed recent past + just" part on this link?

Comment: Let's clarify it this way: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+have+just+seen%2CI+just+saw&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20have%20just%20seen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20just%20saw%3B%2Cc0  It depends on how you understand **just**. If you process it semantically as similar to **ago**, it relegates the action to the past. If you understand it to mean "recently", it connects the past action to the speaker's present, in which case it does not create temporal discord.

Comment: With **wanted**, as presented in your example "I have just wanted to ask a question", *just* in the meaning "recently" is not really a viable option semantically.  You're describing a thing you *wanted* to do a moment ago. Contextually, the present perfect there makes sense  only if you're reporting on your state of mind, *moment-by-moment*.

Comment: I don't object your inputs thank you. I just want to understand whether you agree use of present perfect for the actions that were completed in recent past which are indeed part of history no matter 5 minutes or 5 seconds past since they were completed. Because British also use present perfect this way.

Comment: @bart: My answer and comments are not about the general situations where the present perfect is often used but about whether an accompanying time phrase ("two seconds ago", "earlier this morning", "yesterday" and so forth) creates temporal discord by relegating the action to the past, so that either the time phrase must be dropped or the tense must be switched to simple past.

Comment: I went through what you have written. Thanks again. Can you please elaborate how  "recently" and "a moment ago" differs in my sentence  semantically in line with your comment above where you mention moment-by-moment action? Can't I use "just" in this sentence with recently meaning then?

Comment: Sorry can you clarify as well difference between "recently" and "one moment ago" over a present perfect "just" example with a specific context? Your examples confused me sorry.

Comment: From the point-of-view of tense, there is no difference between "a half-second ago" and "50 million years ago".  ago is ago. You can think of it as a word that means "in the past".  "ago" relegates the action to the past, whereas "recently" casts the action as one that took place on a continuum stretching from the past up to the present moment. "recently" is not disconnected from the present. "ago" is disconnected from it.

Comment: Thanks. May I clarify one more point? If I want to use recently I simply use the word itself why do we use "just" then? In dictionaries there is no such distinctive meaning demarcation of "just"  Recently also means "not long ago" "I have just finished my dinner" In this sentence is it "recently" or "a moment ago"?

Comment: **Ago** means "in the past". "Not long ago" means "in the not distant past". "recently" means "belonging to my sense of the present; I don't consider it to be really in the past yet."   Recently, fairly recently... are terms whose meaning is *relative to* the present.

Comment: Then the logic with regard to recently is just for your interpretation. Can I say this? Sorry it isn't still clear for me how you apply "recently" to the sentences therefore define whether to use present perfect or simple past. I never use a sentence "I have just come from there an hour ago" given by you as an example.

Comment: @bart: "I" is the speaker in my comment above.  There is no objective definition of *the recent*.  It is a subjective view.  The recent refers to whatever in the past *abuts*, in some way, or is seen in relation to, the speaker's present.

Comment: "If the semantics of the sentence allow for the meaning recently, then just can be used with the present perfect, provided there are no other time phrases that relegate the action to the past"  I kindly ask you to clarify what you mean here with some examples in a context. This is the part that puzzles me.

Comment: @Bart: I've given such examples above in the answer.

Comment: Honestly then can you give me a sentence with "just" in present perfect where "recently" cannot be used therefore "just" cannot be applied? I request a simple sentence in a context. Thanks again and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Actually in my original post "wanted to ask" is a completed situation yet it is something that bridges to the present. It was only objected because it meant like "I was wanting to ask for long". Do you use present perfect or simple past if you finished your meal 5 minutes ago? I would use present perfect with just and this is an action completed in recent past. I don't necessarily have to reflect "recently" logic here.

Comment: Taking **just** temporally, the present perfect *I have just wanted* depicts the desire as one that began and completed in the recent past. That is not normally how we speak of desires, as ephemera, and so it strikes my ear as unidiomatic, absent some context to support the notion of evanescence. As I said in a comment above, the statement would make temporal sense if you were recounting your mental state *moment-by-moment*, for example, if a brain surgeon were stimulating areas of the brain:  *I have just wanted to shout* or *I have just wanted to scratch my elbow*.